# Can I compile Visual Studio 2015 header files into dlls and use it in VS2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Background: I want to use mlpack in windows for office work, but for some support reasons, office environment is stuck with Visual Studio 2013. In order to use mlpack, I need to use VS2015. So, I compiled mlpack using VS2015 on my personal machine (Followed this - keon.io/mlpack/mlpack-on-windows/) I included those libraries in VS2013 as per this - https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/wiki/WindowsBuild It didn't work. It gave errors saying certain header files I included are incompatible with VS2013.

Question: Can I create .dll files from headers files in VS2015, and use those dlls instead of including the header files in VS2013? I am not sure how to do this. Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually compatibility problems rise in static libraries, not dlls (shared). Yes, you can compile dlls in any compiler and use them with any other compiler. Even from MinGW to VS. The only thing that matters there is 32/64 bit binary compatibility.

And of course, the more reasonable way to answer this question is the very ancient and old secret methodology that says: ***Try it***! If you face problems there, then people on Stackoverflow can help after you describe a very specific problem.

Comment: My doubt is how to create a dll from header only files? Header files have incompatibility issues. I am looking here -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms235636.aspx and it says we have to include both header and dlls. If that is the case, it breaks again as header itself is incompatible

Comment: @Sashank The headers are just an interface that you can rewrite yourself. You can generally even get any random dll, write an interface for it, and use it in your program. Before you ask these questions, you should try to do something with DLLs. Asking without trying is a bad idea. Trying won't lose you anything. There are tons of examples out there on how to deal with DLLs.